# Titanium chat implementation

Tags: titanium-mobile

I have an task to implement an chat based application to access private data available at server using web service api call.Show all available users from web server and to chat with those persons.Is't possible with titanium development to support on iPhone/Android chat application. If possible let me guide to implement the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course it's possible. And there are a million ways to do this, your question is not very clear.

If its totally web services based [then just use this.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient)

Heres a quick example of posting to a webservice and sending a JSON object:

```
 var getChatMessages = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function(e) {
             var doSomethignWithThis = this.responseText;
        },
        onerror : function(e) {
            Ti.API.info(this.responseText);
            Ti.API.info('SelectActivityStepsByKeyList webservice failed with message : ' + e.error);
        }
    });
    getChatMessages.open('POST', 'http://yourchatserver/GetChats');
    getChatMessages.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    getChatMessages.send({"message" : "How is everyone today?", "user" : "me@me.com});
```

This is not difficult with titanium, the hard part is on the server side. 
[Here is an example project that accomplishes chat through the use of the socket.io library.](http://roguesynaptics.com/post/7056128461/chatsocks) This may be a better approach for you. The link has a video of how it works as well as the full source code.

Comment: How do I execute the sample code to test..can you please give me some details

Comment: Check out the link I gave : the full code is here https://github.com/euforic/ChatSocks#readme